# Can not bundle two files with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have the following webpack configuration file, where I'm trying to make two bundle files for two separate projects:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var INDEX_BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app/public');
var INDEX_APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app/');
var RESULTS_BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/results/public');
var RESULTS_APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/results/');

var config = {
  entry: {
    INDEX_BUILD_DIR: INDEX_APP_DIR,
    RESULTS_BUILD_DIR: RESULTS_APP_DIR
  },
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : [INDEX_APP_DIR, RESULTS_APP_DIR],
        loader : 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I made this structure after looking here:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1189

However, I am getting this issue:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' path/to/project/src/client/app in /path/to/project
```

I can't understand where the issue originates from.

Also, only one file is created named "RESULTS_BUILD_DIR.js" which means that a variable is interpreted literally.

What causes these problems?

Comment: You know that `entry: {INDEX_BUILD_DIR: ...}` will create an object that *literally* has the key "INDEX_BUILD_DIR"? It won't use the value of the variable with the same name as key. I'm asking because you don't use `INDEX_BUILD_DIR` anywhere. Don't know if that's the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things:

1. Error in entry: you're pointing a path to module, so you have to have an index.js file in path/to/project/src/client/app as well as in src/client/results/
2. RESULTS_BUILD_DIR.js yes, this notation filename: '[name].js' says "put the name of the entry and add dot and js - and this would be a result filename"